# I need a method to save an arraylist in my app

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, save

Im working on an app and in it i made an arraylist of strings.
i searched for ways to save the list for the next visit but i did not find a good one.
i tried shared preferences but didn't manage to make it work.

Can someone please help me find the way to save the data in the array list and restore it in every app visit ?

The array i want to save called here "ContactList".

I put my code below:

```
public class Work_Contacts extends Activity {

public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
private ArrayList<String> contactList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> contactList2;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work__contacts);

    Button btnPickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPickContact);
    btnPickContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View _view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });




    contactList=new ArrayList<String>();

   contactList2=new ArrayList<String>();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);

    arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList2);



    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactListView);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    lv.setLongClickable(true);
    lv.setClickable(true);



    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(pos));



            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
        }
    });



    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {

            String url = "tel:"+arrayAdapter2.getItem(pos);
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });






}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT): {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contentUri = data.getData();
            //Phone Name
            Cursor c = managedQuery(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //Phone Number
            String contactId = contentUri.getLastPathSegment();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, Phone._ID + "=?", new String[] { contactId },
                    null);// < - Note, not CONTACT_ID!
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            Boolean numbersExist = cursor.moveToFirst();
            int phoneNumberColumnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String phoneNumber = "";
            while (numbersExist) {
                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberColumnIndex);
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.trim();
                numbersExist = cursor.moveToNext();

            }
            stopManagingCursor(cursor);
            //Set
            arrayAdapter.add(name + " - " + phoneNumber);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            arrayAdapter2.add(phoneNumber);
            arrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }
        break;
    }

    }



}
```

}

Comment: The short answer is that you are asking a really loaded question. The answer depends on what is available to you.  Do you want it in a database (probably) or in a file?  Are you using a framework (I'd think), and which one?  They probably have persistence documentation in the "getting started" app.

Comment: saving in a database is not necessary for me because the app is not online, so savign to file is possible as well, im just looking for the easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the list in sqlite. You can find many examples on the web on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 序列化数据
 * 
 * @param o
 * @param file
 */
public static void serializationOfObject(Object o, File file) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Utility", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

/**
 * 反序列化数据
 * 
 * @param file
 * @return
 */
public static Object deserializationOfObject(File file) {
    if (!file.exists())
        return null;
    Object object = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        object = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Utility", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return object;
}
```

when you want to save,just call `serializationOfObject(arraylist,file);`

when you want to get,call `(ArrayList<T>)deserializationOfObject(file);`

hope to help you.

Comment: And where should i put the code you gave me ?
In a different activity or in the same one with the list ?

Comment: the method is "static",just put them in your Utility class.